# Notepad++ syntax highlighting support for .mapfiles?

Tags: mapserver

I was looking for a language definition for mapserver ".map" files in Notepad++ but could not find anything.

Is there anyone who can recommend / has such a file? an already defined one?

If not, is there an open source text editor that can highlight .map file code for easy ready in windows?

I searched the web for such editors but no luck yet.

Comment: By highlight do you mean syntax highlighting? .map files are just text files. Any code editor should do. What do you mean by easy ready? It is not a programming language.

Comment: Yes, syntax highlighting. Even if it is not a programming language I thought such an option might come in handy. 

If some paid software have support for it, open source text editors could do the same job.

I'll just go forward and define one in this case.

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately, Mapserver isn't really that famous outside of GIS circles. Saw a language definition for Notepad++ btw. You might want to check my answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found one for [Notepad++](https://sites.google.com/site/gianpierocampanella/files). You might have to tweak it a bit as it might be for an old version of Mapserver.

---

You'd have to create your own definition if you insist on using Notepad++. You might want to check [mscompanion](https://code.google.com/p/mscompanion/) though. It has a WYSIWYG mapfile editor and you can instantly visualize your changes. You can find the installer at [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/mscompanion/). Good luck!

Comment: Notepad++ is a very useful viewer/editor (SQL) and also comparing files side by side.

Comment: BTW any luck about automatic indentation for map files? perhaps in Vi?

Answer (score 5):

Found one on GitHub : [MapserverSyntaxHighlighting](https://github.com/AstunTechnology/MapserverSyntaxHighlighting)

It adds a user defined language in N++ ([check this, if you want to create your own](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/resources.html)).

Just put the two files given here :

- userDefineLang.xml -> %appdata%\Notepad++
- mapfile.xml ->
  %programfiles(x86)%\Notepad++\plugins\APIs

You may need to restart N++ or reopen the mapfile.

Answer (score 3):

I maintain an updated and accurate MapServer (7.6) syntax file for Notepad++ at: https://ms4w.com/trac/wiki/Notepad++MapServerStyle

[image: description]