# Notepad++ syntax highlighting for *.map

Tags: mapserver, mapfile, syntax

I can't find how to customize syntax highlighting for mapfile (*.map files) in Notepad++. I actually have add this [syntax file](https://sites.google.com/site/gianpierocampanella/files) recommended in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63139/notepad-syntax-highlighting-support-for-mapfiles). BUT the syntax highlighting is not good, probably because built for an old version of MapServer (see image below where plenty of key-words are not colored properly). I therefore have 2 questions:

1. How can I customize the syntax colorization? I can't access to the 'Mapfile' language via Settings > Style Configurator > Default theme (not in the languages list).
2. How is it possible to make Notepad++ recognize *.map files automatically. When I open such a file, it is colored like a txt file and the extension *.map is not recognized.

[image]

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/413524/how-do-i-get-notepad-to-associate-a-file-type-with-a-language but closing this post as not a GIS question

Comment: OK sorry, I posted on stackoverflow...